# Suggestion List with Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, autosuggest

There is a FormGroup with a FormArray and relative FormControl populated.
I built a service (valuechange Observable) that with a given string this look up for similar word in a "dictionary" array. the service gives back an array of object that should populate a suggestion list right under the input.

The suggestion list is formed by 3 terms similar to this.

I give 'table' string and returns:

```
  [
    {distance: 1, match : 'Table'},
    {distance: 3, match : 'Fabules'},
    {distance: 5, match : 'Ramioles'},
  ]
```

Distance is calculated with Levenstein algorithm and indicates how many changing has to be perform to obtain given word.

Now I need to build the action. I click on the term, the value change and the list disappear.

Important is that for each input populated the service start with (focus) and gives back its suggestion list.

**component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm">
     <fieldset formArrayName="parameters">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let par of parameters.controls" [formGroup]="par">
             <input formControlName="name" />
             <ul class="filter-select">
                <li *ngFor="let r of results" class="filter-select-list">
                   {{ r.match }}
                </li>
            </ul>
         </ng-container>        
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

I don't want use libraries like ng2-completer or material autocomplete and most important I cannot use datalist because if the given string is "tablered" and in the dictionary is present the word "Table Red", The datalist does not shows up.

And second datalist is HTML5 only with cross browsing issue.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

RECAP:

1. Each inputs of this array must hook to a service ON FOCUS that look for a word in a dictionary (done with one input only - look below - but not in a *ngFor)
2. This service return an array and populates a suggestion list (done)
3. Then click on the suggestion
4. The value change
5. The list disappear

**component.html**

```
    <input [formControl]="queryField" type="text" />
```

**service.ts**

```
   this.queryField.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe( value => {  
     this.results = this._searchService.spell(value)
  })
```

**SECOND PART**

I came up with something like below.
With an Observable on the input focus the list is populated.

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'my-autocomplete-input',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ul class="filter-select">
      <li *ngFor="let r of autosuggestList" class="filter-select-list">
          <div (click)="editInput(r.match)">{{ r.match }}</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  `
  })
  export class AutocompleteComponent  {
    @ContentChild("input") input: ElementRef;
    @Input() autosuggestList;


    constructor(
      private _searchService: SearchService,
    ) {}

    editInput(res) {
      this.input.nativeElement.value = res;
      this.autosuggestList = [];
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'focus')
          .subscribe((data: KeyboardEvent) => {
            this.autosuggestList = this._searchService.spell(this.input.nativeElement.value)
          });
    }

  }
```

but then the form array is not updated I have to press something on the input to let change the value inside the FormControl "name".

How can I patch/update the form from the contentChild? more precise in the editInput function?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you have two inputs: name and value... I assume one, for inputting something is enough and then you get a dropdown to select something and fill it into the input. No?

Make a AutocompleteInputComponent so you have your code in a nice dedicated place. There you place an  that has always to be of type `<input>` (in that component you declare `@ContentChild('input') input: ElementRef;`)

Now you can say in your parent's component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let par of parameters.controls" [formGroup]="par">
    <my-autocomplete-input [autosuggestList]="valuechange">
        <input formControlName="name"/>
    </my-autocomplete-input>
</ng-container>
```

If you need the second input too you can use css-selectors to differentiate between content children: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: forget about value.. btw I dont want a dropdown select like select-options but an ul - li

Comment: you can have `ul li`, `div div` or whatever you want. You pass in the `autosuggestList `-list to that component and make an *ngFor like you did here over the elements of that list.

Comment: ok  i got it but when i updated the input value; it does not update the formvalue; see the second part.